# Skip validation conditionally JSF

Tags: jsf-2

Requirement is to skip field validation conditionally. When user selects add, the form fields should be validated and values added to the table.
If edit is clicked, form field validation should be skipped but bean values should be copied to the input fields.

```
<composite:nameInput id="name" value="#{buyer.name}" 
  disableBeanValidation ="#{param['skipBeanValidation']}"/>
<h:commandLink action="#{buyerBacking.cancelEdit}" value="cancel"/>

 <h:dataTable value="#{bean.list}">
    <h:commandLink value="Edit" action="#{buyerBacking.edit}">
     <f:param name="skipBeanValidation" value="true" /> 
    </h:commandLink>
 </h:dataTable>

   <h:commandLink id="add" action="#{buyerBacking.add}"/>
```

Name Input composite component

```
<h:inputText id="fName" value="#{bean.fname}">
     <f:validateBean disabled="#{cc.attrs. disableBeanValidation}"/>
</h:inputText>
```

If user enter's details and selects add, the details are added to the table.
If validation errors, we display the error message.

Then user selects edit, the values are copied to the input fields.
User selects cancel edit, the values are removed from the input fields.
If user selects edit again, we get a index out of bound exception error. Index out of bound exception for name_firstName.

But this does not occur if user selects add and cancel edit is selected.
Does it has to do with the view parameter being passed which is null somehow?

javax.faces.FacesException: Unexpected error restoring state for component with id frmAddAuthBuyerBR_inpAuthBuyerBRName_prefix_input.  Cause: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0.
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.StateManagementStrategyImpl$2.visit(StateManagementStrategyImpl.java:272)
    at com.sun.faces.component.visit.FullVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(FullVisitContext.java:151)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1612)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1626)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1626)
    at javax.faces.component.UINamingContainer.visitTree(UINamingContainer.java:163)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1626)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1626)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1626)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1626)
    at javax.faces.component.UINamingContainer.visitTree(UINamingContainer.java:163)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1626)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1626)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1626)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:371)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1626)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is incomplete as you're nowhere showing how `disableBeanValidation` is implemented and how you're passing the `#{param[skipBeanValidation]}` around.

But it should *basically* boil down to:

```
<f:validateBean disabled="#{param.skipBeanValidation}" />

...

<h:commandLink value="Edit" action="#{buyerBacking.edit}"/>
    <f:param name="skipBeanValidation" value="true" />
</h:commandLink>
```

Please note that `#{param.skipBeanValidation}` is quite different from `#{param[skipBeanValidation]}` (but the same as `#{param['skipBeanValidation']}`). Also please note that the desired request parameter to skip the bean validation is been passed as a HTTP request parameter, exactly as is been expected by `#{param}`.

Comment: I have updated the code in my question. I have coded the same way you suggested, but as asked in the question, selecting cancel and then selecting edit causing indexoutof bound exception.

Comment: The stacktrace would be helpful.

Comment: Added the stacktrace. Please let me know if additional information is needed. Even if I hardcode the disabled value to true. It works only for the first time. When cancel is clicked and then edit, the validation takes place even though disabled is true. For the Cancel method I am returning  an empty String.

Comment: That's a pretty serious problem. Are you creating components dynamically? Are you using `binding` somewhere?

Comment: There is no usage of binding in our code. And also the components are rendered based on a flag but not created dynamically.

Comment: Okay, which Mojarra version? Have you tried upgrading to the latest, which is currently 2.1.14?

Comment: Instead of validateBean can we use required="false" to resolve the issue. I have tried this but it results in validating empty fields.