# Skip validation on re-render and apply only on form submit

Tags: java, validation, jsf-2, richfaces

I have an input field where user enters some product name. Depending on an entered name particular details of this product should be shown. On input change I'm getting the product from data source by the current field value and re-render product details using `AJAX`. So far user can not see product details until he enters correct name.

Here is the code sample:

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputText id="product" value="#{myBean.product}" required="true" converter="productConverter">
        <a4j:ajax event="change" render="product, details"/>
    </h:inputText>

    <rich:message for="product" ajaxRendered="true"/>

    <h:panelGroup id="details">
        <h:outputText rendered="#{not empty myBean.product}" value="#{myBean.product.details}"/>
    </h:panelGroup>

    <a4j:commandButton execute="@form" render="@form" value="Validate" action="validate"/>
</h:form>
```

**Converter**:

```
public class ProductConverter implements Converter {

public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String name) {
    return (name != null && ProductDataSource.projectExist(name)) ? new Product(name) : null;
}

public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
    return (value instanceof Product) ? ((Product) value).getName() : "";
}
```

The product is mandatory field, so form can't be submitted until the correct name is entered. So far when user enters incorrect name, converter returns null and validation fails. But what I want is to validate this field only on form submit, and skip validation when re-rendering input field. I tried to apply `immediate="true"` on both `a4j:ajax` and `h:inputText` but nothing helped. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

(I'm using JSF 2, Richfaces 4)

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/13250991/1199132

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the `required` attribute evaluate `true` only if the submit button is pressed. You can do that by checking the presence of its client ID in the request parameter map like so:

```html
<h:inputText ... required="#{not empty param[button.clientId]}" />
...
<a4j:commandButton binding="#{button}" ... />
```

*(no, you do not need to bind it to a bean property, the code is complete as-is)*

Answer (score 0):

For skipping Jsf validation you had added to the form 
write immediate="true" in a4j:commandButton

Comment: Adding `immediate="true"` to `a4j:commandButton` will skip validation on submit. I want the opposite behavior - validate only on submit

Answer (score 0):

Try to use something like

```
<a4j:outputPanel ajaxRendered="true">
   <h:inputText id="product" value="#{myBean.product}" required="true" converter="productConverter">
      <a4j:support event="onchange" reRender="details" ajaxSingle="true"/>
   </h:inputText>

   <rich:message id="product" for="details" ajaxRendered="true">
   <h:panelGroup id="details">
      <h:outputText rendered="#{not empty myBean.product}" value="#{myBean.product.details}"/>
   </h:panelGroup>

</a4j:outputPanel>
```

The main idea is to use **ajaxSingle="true"** to avoid complete output panel validation.