# Skip validation of a form on re-render with Richfaces

Tags: validation, jsf, richfaces, rerender

I use Richfaces 3.1.2 and JSF 1.1

I have a `textarea` with two buttons inside a form : `Submit` and `Update`

1. the button `Submit` submits the form
2. One click on the button `Update` adds some text in the `textarea`

A validator is used inside the textarea, this validator throws an exception if the textarea only contains the name of the current connected user, for instance if the current connected user is "root" and the textarea contains "root", then an exception should be thrown

The code of the Textarea (by default it contains the name of the current connected user):

```
<h:panelGroup id="messagePanel">
    <h:inputTextarea id="message" label="Update" value="#{beanName.message}">
        <f:validator validatorId="messageValidator" />
    </h:inputTextarea>
</h:panelGroup>
```

The submit button :

```
<h:commandLink id="validerLink" value="Submit" action="accueil" 
    actionListener="#{beanName.saveInformation}">
    <f:param value="#{param.evenementId}" name="evenementId" />
</h:commandLink>
```

And the update button :

```
<a4j:commandLink id="inclureRapportLink" value="Update" 
    actionListener="#{beanName.updateText}" reRender="message">
    <f:param name="evenementId" value="#{param.evenementId}" />
</a4j:commandLink>
```

The problem : If the textarea contains the name of the current connected user, the button `Update` doesn't update the text because the validator throws an exception.

So what I want to do is to disable the validator, but only if the user clicks on the button `Update`

I tried to add `immediate="true"` in the update button, but that didn't worked because apparently `immediate="true"` and `reRender="message"` doesn't work together (The bean is updated, but not the front).

I also tried this solution here : [Skip validation on re-render and apply only on form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14862903/skip-validation-on-re-render-and-apply-only-on-form-submit) but that didn't worked either, I got the error `Undefined property clientId`, and the validator is called even if the `required` property is set to `false`.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Why can/don't want you use `validator` from `h:inputTextArea`? PS. I always like to guess what are RF's and JSF's versions.

Comment: The update button adds/changes some text in the textarea, but if I click on this button, the validator is called, and sometimes the validator throws an exception, in that case the text in the textarea field is not updated, I want that the text is always updated (when I click on the button), so I need to disable the validator when the user clicks on the update button.