# Skip validation but still keeps submitted values

Tags: jsf

I have this screen strategy. Customer and Contact Person are One-Many relationship. When user click "Create contact person", I'd like to skip validation on (A), after "Save" contact person, the input values in (A) should be retained.

For example:

- Enter customer name "John"
- Click "Create contact person", enter contact person
- "Save". "John" should be shown again

"Create" button:

```
<h:commandLink class="btn"
    action="#{contactPersonController.add()}"
    styleClass="btn pull-right plusButton">
    <i class="icon-plus"></i>&#160;#{msg.add}
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{contactPersonController.itemEditable}" value="#{addable}"></f:setPropertyActionListener>
</h:commandLink>
```

- I tried "immediate=true". It skips validation but doesn't retain the values submitted before in (A).
- Somebody says "f:ajax" but I don't know how to apply in this case.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use < f:param name="skipValidation" ... >

```
<h:inputText id="customerName" styleClass=""
    value="#{customerCreationController.customerDto.customerName}"
    label="#{msg.customerName}" readonly="#{!customerCreationController.update and !customerCreationController.create}">
    <f:validateRequired disabled="#{param.skipValidation}"/>
    <f:validateLength maximum="#{shortStrLen}" disabled="#{param.skipValidation}"/>
</h:inputText>

<h:commandLink class="btn"
    action="#{contactPersonController.add()}"
    styleClass="btn pull-right plusButton">
    <i class="icon-plus"></i>&#160;#{msg.add}
    <f:param name="skipValidation" value="true"/>
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{contactPersonController.itemEditable}" value="#{addable}"></f:setPropertyActionListener>
</h:commandLink>
```

Ref: [Skip validation conditionally JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13240701/skip-validation-conditionally-jsf/13250991#13250991)